# solr filter query range

Tags: filter, solr, range

in my index i have a multivalued doc field named "counter". it stores values like counter:[5, 12, 75, ...] and so on.

if i try to retrieve only docs where the min value of this field is greater than another value i cant get the expected result. i tried with the following filter query:

```
field(counter, min)\:[10 TO *]
```

this is the field type used and the field declaration in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="integer" class="solr.TrieIntField" omitNorms="true"/>           

<field name="counter" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

there are no errors but not the expected result, unfortunately. thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `fq={!frange l=10}field(counter,min)`?  Using a function query directly as a field name in a query don't work as far as I know.

Comment: hi, sorry about the delay and thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can [use the `frange` query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-parsers.html) to retrieve documents that match a range of values returned by a function:

```
fq={!frange l=10}field(counter,min)
```

> The FunctionRangeQParser extends the QParserPlugin and creates a range query over a function. This is also referred to as frange, as seen in the examples below.
>
> Other parameters:
>
> *l*, The lower bound, optional
>
> *u*, The upper bound, optional
>
> *incl*, Include the lower bound: true/false, optional, default=true
>
> *incu*, Include the upper bound: true/false, optional, default=true